# Why does Safari respond with "The operation cannot be completed" when registering WebAuthn Credentials?

Tags: safari, webauthn

When implementing WebAuthn authenticator registration on my site, I ran into the issue that during the attestation / registration process, Safari returns a modal saying "The operation cannot be completed" after I attest using one of my devices. The process works on other browsers, but fails on Safari.

[The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynFd1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Safari fails WebAuthn registration for any attestation request asking for an additional [attestation statement](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#attestation-statement) via the [attestation conveyance](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#attestation-conveyance).

I couldn't find this documented anywhere, but I played around with the [Auth0 WebAuthn registration debugger](https://webauthn.me/debugger) and came to the conclusion that the `"attestation"` field was what was causing this popup. I would assume that Safari is being super defensive against any additional data being given about WebAuthn enabled devices via the protocol?

But in summary, ensuring:

```
navigator.credentials.create({
  ...
  attestation: 'none',
});
```

worked to prevent the popup for me.